# Validate Doctrine entities with Symfony Validator

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine

I have difficulties integrating the Symfony validator component with Doctrine (standalone, not using the complete Symfony framework). So far I have managed to register the annotation contraints in Doctrine's AnnotationRegistry and hook into the lifecycle callbacks, but how would I actually retrieve a validator and parse the annotations in the lifecycle method?

My entity looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="username_UNIQUE", columns={"username"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        // how do I retrieve the validator?

        // $validator->validate($this);
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=45)
     */
    protected $username;

    /** ... */
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you are not using symfony fullstack, you should manually create a validator servie to use it.

See [Usage Section of Validator component readme](https://github.com/symfony/Validator#usage)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Length(min = 3)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Assert\Email
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $email;

    public function __construct($name, $email)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @Assert\True(message = "The user should have a Google Mail account")
     */
    public function isGmailUser()
    {
        return false !== strpos($this->email, '@gmail.com');
    }
}
```

The validator

```
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
    ->enableAnnotationMapping()
    ->getValidator();

$user = new User('John Doe', 'john@example.com');

$violations = $validator->validate($user);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! However, if an exception is thrown in the lifecycle callback due to failed validation, the entity manager will close. Is there a way to prevent this? For now I just removed the lifecycle callbacks and manually validate the entity in my repositorie's save method, which seems to be working, but doesn't strike me as the most elegant solution.

Comment: Not sure it is not to late, but just use try..catch to handle this manually. Expect some validation exception and handle it properly.